# Stack Data Frames on top of one another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dataframes :

1st dataframe

```
Countrey    2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005

canada      779      771     754     740     760     747
mexico      1311.2  1285.2  1271.2  1276.5  1270.6  1281
usa         836     814     810     800     802     799
India       914     892     888     878     880     877
China       992     970     966    956       958    955
```

2nd dataframe

```
year        2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005
data        1.1     1.2     1.3    1.4       1.5    1.6
```

i would like to merge above these two dataframe in following way?is it possible?

```
data        1.1      1.2    1.3     1.4      1.5    1.6
Countrey    2000    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005
canada      779     771      754    740      760    747
mexico      1311.2  1285.2  1271.2  1276.5  1270.6  1281
usa         836      814    810     800      802    799
India       914      892    888     878      880    877
China       992      970    966     956      958    955
Sum        4832.2   4732.2  4689.2  4650.5  4670.6  4659
```

also i wants the sum of each column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: i didnt find answer as you provided that solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pandas.concat()` or `DataFrame.append()` , check pandas document its easily available with examples.

Comment: could you please suggest me with some example,its availble with left,right,inner & outer merge but i did not find merging of top of df

Comment: df2.append(df1) try with this then after that , sum up your new data frame to get the sum column wise.

Comment: df2 dataframe showing left side of df1,wants top on df

Comment: put axis = 1 in append function.